# WPF, C# - SelectAll in CheckEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress-wpf

how to make `CheckEdit` Select All.

Xaml automatically generate `checkEdit`

```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" x:Name="MyCheck" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3"  
                               IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

        <Button x:Name="filtrButton" Content="Filtr" Command="{Binding FiltrCommand}"  Padding="5" Margin="3" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="CheckALL" Content="Select All" Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding AllSelected}" />
```

C#

```
        private bool? _allSelected = true;
    public bool? AllSelected
    {
        get { return _allSelected; }
        set
        {
            _allSelected = value;

          MyProperty.ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = value);

            OnPropertyChange("AllSelected");
        }
    }
    public List<MyCheckBox> MyProperty
    {
        get { return TempList; }
        set
        {
            TempList = value;
            OnPropertyChange("MyProperty");
        }
    }
/// добавление название файла и его select
        public ViewModel(){
       TempList = new List<MyCheckBox>();

        foreach (var type in tempUniqueList)
        {
            TempList.Add(new MyCheckBox(type, _allSelected));
        }

        MyProperty = TempList;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a collection of CheckBox ? `dxe:CheckEdit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_allSelected is unnecessary, because it's state comes from whether the other items are checked or not. *(Note: This is different to selection, which means something else in ItemsControls)*

```
public bool? AllSelected
{
    get 
    { 
        // Check if all are checked
        if (!MyProperty.Any(x => !x.IsChecked))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if none are checked
        if (!MyProperty.Any(x => x.IsChecked))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Otherwise some are checked.
        return null;
    }

    set
    {
        _allSelected = value;

        MyProperty.ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = value);

        OnPropertyChange("AllSelected");
    }
}
```

Now, the other important thing is that you need to raise *OnPropertyChanged("AllSelected")* whenever the IsChecked() value for one of the items is changed. This is not a very nice solution at this point. You need to hook the PropertyChanged event for each item inserted into "MyProperty", test whether it is the *IsChecked* property, and if it is then raise PropertyChanged.

Personally, I tend to think of this sort of thing as more part of the View, rather than the View Model. I mean, a "Select All/Select None" checkbox is really an extension of the ItemsControl, conceptually. So you would probably be fully justified to do this in code-behind and just hook up to the Checked() events in your DataTemplate.